Azure Service Bus - Are sessions the best approach to enforce ordering of interleaved messages whilst maintaining high throughput?
Background
I have a service that will subscribe to a topic to receive transactional update events for an entity type (new, pending approval, approved, rejected etc). On average, I would expect to receive only 3 events per entity. I would like to ensure that the messages for each entity are always processed in the order they were added to the topic, regardless of how many subscriber instances are running.
The Sessions feature should cover this if I use my domain entity ID as the SessionId. But I see two downsides:

I don't know how long the gap will be between messages. It could be almost instant, it could be a day. So how would I pick a session timeout?
Keeping a session open blocks the subscriber from processing other messages in other sesisons, limiting throughput.

Potential solution
The best solution to me seems to be using my domain entity ID as the SessionId and closing the session after every message. On the face of it, this would allow me to guarantee the processing order of events for an entity across multiple subscriber instances whilst maintaining high throughput.
Questions
This seems very logical and obvious to me - but everywhere I read about sessions suggest that if you are closing the session after a single message, then you are not using sessions correctly. But I just don't see why, as it seems a neat way to solve a common problem to me.
So the main question: Are there any problems/downsides to my proposed solution of closing the session after every message?
And some sub-questions that will help inform/explain the answer to the main question:

Is the overhead of opening and closing sessions significant?
Are there any guidelines for the maximum number on concurrent sessions on a subscriber instance? (for this setting)
Are there any alternative ways of solving this problem I should consider?


If I understand your concern correctly, you've got a mistaken assumption above with the statement "if I get two messages almost instantaneuosly and they are picked up by different subscriber instance"  In order for a receiver to read from a session, that receiver must hold an exclusive lock on the session.   It is not possible for two different receivers to read messages from the same session concurrently.   The receiver that holds the lock would be the only one reading from the session and sessions themselves guarantee ordering of messages within a session.

Yes sorry thats badly written by me, thats supposed to be the justification for needing the session. Will update, thanks

Sessions guarantee ordered message processing in the order those were sent, but on one important condition - there are no failures in processing. If you have a message in a given session that, for whatever reason, ends up in a DLQ, the processing of the next message in the session_will_ take place. It's not enough to assume that sessions handle the message processing order. If order and all message processing are essential, you must validate that the 2nd aspect is addressed.
